# join two tables where unique id is 0 in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

below are the two tables  1st is media_taxonomy and 2nd is media_taxonomy_map to join

media_taxonomy:

[image: This is table media_taxonomy]

media_taxonomy_map:

[image: This is table media_taxonomy_map]

here is my sql query

```
select * from media_taxonomy_map as mtm
join media_taxonomy as mt
on mtm.media_taxonomy_id = mt.media_taxonomy_id
```

here is the result:
[image]

BUT, I also want the rows in the joined table where media_taxonomy_id is 0 in media_taxonomy_map table

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want *all* rows in the table.  If so, just use `left join`:

```
select *
from media_taxonomy_map as mtm left join
     media_taxonomy as mt
     on mtm.media_taxonomy_id = mt.media_taxonomy_id;
```

If you specifically want matches or `0`, then you can filter:

```
select *
from media_taxonomy_map as mtm left join
     media_taxonomy as mt
     on mtm.media_taxonomy_id = mt.media_taxonomy_id
where mtm.media_taxonomy_id = 0 or mt.media_taxonomy_id is not null;
```